# No gradients provided for any variable with random data and proper model construction

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```py
import tensorflow as tf

length = 500
data = tf.transpose([range(length),
                     tf.random.uniform([length], minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
dataset.shuffle(length)

train_length = int(length / 5 * 4)
train_data = dataset.take(train_length)
test_data = dataset.skip(train_length)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'], run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(train_data.batch(10), validation_data=test_data.batch(10), epochs=10)
```

Why does it throw error

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].

I just want to use some random data to train the model in order to learn tensorflow. How do I fix the code?

Comment: You need to add `input_shape` to the first layer, i.e., to Dense(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataset shape is incorrect in the OP's code. I will suggest to add the following check before model.fit

```py
assert isinstance(train_data.element_spec, tuple) and len(train_data.element_spec) > 0, \
    'When x is dataset, its members must be a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights). Currently your tuple size is 0.'
```

Your code fails with the assert because the examples in your dataset is one element instead of two.

The minimal change is to create dataset like this

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```